# Drush script memory problem

Tags: 8, drush

I'm running a long drush script and its causing memory problems.

Then I tried debbuging it and I have this very simple code:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user');

foreach ($emails as $i => $email) {
    $users = $query->loadByProperties(['mail' => $email]);
    $user = reset($users);

    unset($user);
    unset($users);
}
```

When I ran the script I noticed that the memory increases dramatically as the script is running. What is causing this memory issue?

Comment: Check the code of https://www.drupal.org/project/drush9_batch_processing

Comment: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drush9_batch_processing

Comment: @leymannx This doesn't help me, I already have a drush script, I don't need a module, I'm just wondering why was it using a lot memory.

Comment: It's an example module which explains how to implement a batch process in a Drush command. A batch process is what you need to process the users in small chunks and in between these chunks release memory again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The memory issue is caused by the internal entity cache which you can release by using [$storage->resetCache()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityStorageBase.php/function/ContentEntityStorageBase%3A%3AresetCache/8.9.x).

You've named the user storage $query, so replace the unset() commands with:

```
$query->resetCache([$user->id()]);
$query->resetCache(array_keys($users));
```

Recently core added the advice to use the entity.memory_cache service instead, to only clear the in-memory cache and not invalidate the entities in the database:

```
\Drupal::service('entity.memory_cache')->deleteAll();
```

This is more efficient, in your script and also for subsequent loads of the entities.

Reference: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityStorageBase.php/function/ContentEntityStorageBase%3A%3AresetCache/9.2.x